# How to display an Esri Map on MVC view from an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, esri

I would like to know how to display an Esri Map on a ASP.Net MVC view from an HTML file.

I have an HTML file that contains a JavaScript code. This file can display the map and the widgets when I open it with any internet browser. It is working fine. But now I want to display that map on an ASP.Net MVC view. This is what I have done:

```html
<h2 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#projectmap">Project Map</h2>
<div id="projectmap" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">

      @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Application/default.html")))
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it displays only the Sketch widget, it does not display the map. I have also tried to write the JavaScript code manually on the .cshtml file and use the div container to display the map, it still displays the Sketch widget only. I have also tried the partial views, it does not work.

Below is the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Load a basic WebMap - 4.14</title>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css" />

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>

    <script>
        var x;
        var y;
        require(["esri/views/MapView", "esri/WebMap", "esri/config", "esri/widgets/Sketch", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"], function (MapView, WebMap, esriConfig, Sketch, GraphicsLayer) {
            /************************************************************
             * Creates a new WebMap instance. A WebMap must reference
             * a PortalItem ID that represents a WebMap saved to
             * arcgis.com or an on-premise portal.
             *
             * To load a WebMap from an on-premise portal, set the portal
             * url with esriConfig.portalUrl.
             ************************************************************/
            esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://portal.environment.gov.za/portal";

            var webmap = new WebMap({
                portalItem: {
                    // autocasts as new PortalItem()
                    id: "04582be14885483da48f29398960f653"
                }

            });

            var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

            /************************************************************
             * Set the WebMap instance to the map property in a MapView.
             ************************************************************/
            var view = new MapView({
                map: webmap,
                container: "viewDiv"
            });

            webmap.layers.add(graphicsLayer);

            var sketch = new Sketch({
                layer: graphicsLayer,
                view: view,
                container: "viewDiv"
            });

            view.ui.add(sketch, "top-left");

            // Listen to sketch widget's create event.
            sketch.on("create", function (event) {
                // check if the create event's state has changed to complete indicating
                // the graphic create operation is completed.
                console.log(view.zoom);
                //if (event.state === "complete") {
                //    // remove the graphic from the layer. Sketch adds
                //    // the completed graphic to the layer by default.
                //    graphicsLayer.remove(event.graphic);

                //    // use the graphic.geometry to query features that intersect it
                //    selectFeatures(event.graphic.geometry);
                //}

                console.info(event.graphic.geometry);
                x = event.graphic.geometry.x;
                y = event.graphic.geometry.y;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the case since I can't see the content of your html file that contains the esri code. But ensure that the `<div>` you place your map on has a CSS property that gives a set width and height. If you just place the map in a `<div>` that has no explicit width or height then the div makes itself 0x0, making the map invisible. Recommend posting the content of your .html file for more help

Comment: Thank you very much R10t I will post the the HTML code.

Comment: It looks like the issue is your width and height. You are using a `%` value of width and height but the parent container is 0x0 so a width of 100% is still 0x0. Try setting your `#viewDiv` width and height both to something constant like `200px`